# MySQL join and merge multiple results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using 3-tables model to build a kind of tags system.

**Table 1: Clients**

- client_id (pk)
- client_name

**Table 2: Workplaces**

- workplace_id (pk)
- workplace_name

**Table 3: ClientWorkplace:**

- client_id (pk)
- workplace_id (pk)

One client is allowed to have multiple workplaces. Below is example data in table 3:

- 1 | 1
- 1 | 3
- 1 | 5

I have built the insert and delete client pages successfully. Currently I'm building the edit client page which show current client name and checkbox inputs & workplace names as labels for all workplace types (which ones having relation with the current client will be checked). But I have no idea about the correct SQL query statement.

The expect result for specified client_id 1 should basically be:

cliend_id: 1 | client_name: "my client name" | workplace_ids: "1,3,5"

Please help ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Could you show us your expected output so that there is no confusion?  This looks like a simple series of joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch them using `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT workplace_name, client_name
FROM Workplaces w
INNER JOIN ClientWorkplace cw ON cw.workplace_id = w.workplace_id 
INNER JOIN Clients c ON cw.client_id = c.client_id
ORDER BY w.workplace_id
```

It will fetch all the workplaces and belonging clients. Run a loop and process the data as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to join your 3 tables

```
SELECT c.client_name, w.workplace_name 
FROM Clients c
LEFT JOIN ClientWorkplace cwp ON cwp.client_id = c.client_id
LEFT JOIN Workplaces w ON w.workplace_id = cwp.workplace_id
```

Here's the complete reference for [MYSQL JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !